# Iterate through a list on button press

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I've 3 objects in my list, but I only want the first element to be active. Then, when I press a button, I want the list to move forward one, so the next item in the list is now active and the first isn't.

I have the following code:

```
void OnClick()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < activateTexture.Count; i++)
    {
        activateTexture[0].SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

This only displays the first item in the list (which I want) but I'm stuck on working out how to move through the list.

Could someone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the initial texture active multiple times. Instead, keep track of the current one. Then, each time the code is triggered it can deactivate the one it's on, then move to the next one and activate it.

(Overly commented code below simply to make sure it's explained regarding this answer. I wouldn't normally put comments like this in my code)

```
void Start()
{
    // Initialize all textures to be inactive
    for(int i = 0; i < activateTexture.Count; i++)
    {
        activateTexture[i].SetActive(false);
    }

    // Activate the first texture
    activateTexture[0].SetActive(true);
}

// Store the index of the currently active texture
private int activeTextureIndex = 0;

void OnClick()
{
    // Disable the current
    activateTexture[activeTextureIndex].SetActive(false);

    // Increment the index
    activeTextureIndex = (activeTextureIndex + 1) % activateTexture.Length;

    // Activate a texture based upon the new index
    activateTexture[activeTextureIndex].SetActive(true);
}
```

Note also that I've used the modulo operator `%` to cycle the list.

**EDIT: Corrected due to concerns of integer overflow**